# Unable to get highcharts image from highcharts export server using rails httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I used http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server to set up a java phantomjs based export server using jetty. I am able to run the export server locally. I need to make a post call from my rails app to get the rendered image.I read this link http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside and came to know that I simply have to wrap the options in a json structure while making the post call.So I wrote this code in rails

```
 options = {
 infile: {
        {
  xAxis: {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
   135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
   }]
  } 
 }
} 

@response = HTTParty.post('http://localhost:8080/highcharts-export-  web', :body => options.to_json, 
:headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
 puts @response
```

I am getting the highchart export server's homepage as the response instead of the intended chart. So i came to the conclusion that the format of the post parameters must be wrong.I have been googling for the right format for some time but to no avail. Can any point me in the right direction towards the format of the POST request through which I can get the intended chart?

Answer (score 0):

Right post example format using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}"}' 127.0.0.1:3003
```

Also example using httpie:

```
echo '{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}"}' | http POST localhost:3003
```

Tested on newest version of phantomjs and highcharts-convert.js. Server started with options:

```
phantomjs highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 3003
```

After sending post you should receive Base64 encoded image.

[Generated chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGR7F.png)

Regards.

Comment: I tried the curl command but I am not getting any output.If there are any mistakes in the url or request parameters the response is the highcharts export server home page. Else the command executes and doesn't return anything. Where can I check the output? Is it not supposed to print out the reponse?

Comment: I checked out the logs and found that I am recieving a 302 server error. May be there is something wrong with the header parameters or url that I am using

Comment: Did you follow the guide of how to setup your export server?
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/tree/master/phantomjs